# Palm OS 5.4 (Garnet) IR programming (Use CIR on IrDa port)

Tags: c++, c, mobile, palm-os, garnet-os

I would like to create an open source alternative to Palm OS programs like Noviiremote and Omniremote.

I need to access the IR port of my Tungsten E2 and use it to transmit remote control type signals (I assume NEC and/or RC-5).

Are there any libraries out there I could use? If not, how do I go about transmitting raw codes via the IrDa port? I am new to Palm OS programming, but I am fairly familiar with C++/C#.

I read the programming companion and reference, and they did not seem to cover this.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should add that I have downloaded the Garnet OS development suite, so I believe I am set in the IDE/compiler department.

Comment: Also, I just realized that this would probably have to hook into the firmware, and would therefore be somewhat device specific. Thus, another helpful item would be a specification of the firmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I am asking the wrong question, so I am going to mark this answered and ask a new one.

What I really need is a way to translate RC-5 to serial bits, which I think is possible, since I can use raw IR.

New question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182235/sending-rc-5-ir-signals-serially-using-raw-ir-on-garnet